# Рамка вокруг изображения, которое является ссылкой

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. У меня появилась необходимость создать простенький интернет-магазин. После прикручивания скриптов вокруг изображения-ссылки в некоторых браузерах проявляться цветная рамка. Я никак не могу понять, откуда она вылазит. Ни в таблице стилей, ни в самом HTML она не прописана. Рамка исчезает, если отключить скрипт.

[image]

Comment: Добрый вечер. У меня возникла необходимость купить простенькую машину. После того, как я прикрутил какую-то фигнюшку к антенне, у меня стали запотевать стекла, когда проезжаю по каким-то дорогам, по другим всё нормально. Я проверил дворники работают нормально, жидкость в омывателе тоже есть. Если открутить фигнюшку от антенны, то всё становится нормально. Помогите плиз.

Comment: Благодарю =)
Очень познавательная история!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно из-за стилей ссылок, то есть если изображение является ссылкой, то появляется рамка вокруг него. Одно из решений, добавить свойство border со значением none к селектору img в css. Вот здесь есть [пример](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-ubrat-ramku-vokrug-izobrazheniy-ssylok).